# Angularjs with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've gone through many references regarding Angularjs With ionic. Find out that Ionic gives a nice framework to develop mobile app.

However I am having a confusion. Now I am developing a responsive web application mainly using with bootstrap(foundation also nice one for responsive app).

In many references, they have mentioned like Ionic used to develop mobile app like native mobile app.

Is there any possibility to design the same app for desktop view? (Seriously I don't find any references for this).

1. If so, can you please provide some references?
2. If not, how can I develop the same app for desktop view?

Comment: You are trying to use Ionic to develop a website for desktop as well?

Comment: So first create an app, then a website that looks like the app you created firstly?

Comment: Yes, I want to develop a website for mobile, desktop and ipad as well like responsive web sites. For example, http://start-angular.github.io/sb-admin-angular/preview/#/dashboard/home…. If you resize the browser, you may know how the website will render for different device size.

Comment: Then you don't need Ionic. With Ionic you will be able to package your HTML5 app as a native one and upload it to the markets (Google play and App store). As I understood your last comment you don't need this. If you want your application will be accessible using the browser in all platforms (mobile and desktop), you can just develop it using AngularJS, and use some CSS framework that lets you make it responsive, like bootstrap, for example.

Comment: Thanks. As of now I am doing the responsive site only. But When I saw Ionic, the mobile app looks in a great way better than responsive web app for mobile. So Can I do responsive site with ionic for mobile and desktop. Do they provide this option?

Comment: @jjimenez Agree with you there. It should be the other way around. Website to App with Ionic will play to its advantage.

Comment: Yes @RyanFung. Is there any docs for that? developing web app and mobile app with Ionic?